# (( '127.0.0.1', 8080)) already shut down

Tags: linux, debian, cherrypy, beagleboneblack, beagleboard

I am trying to run a server in BeagleBone Black using CherryPy and following this tutorial http://docs.cherrypy.org/en/latest/install.html, and every time I run it I have this error message

```
ENGINE HTTP Server cherrypy._cpwsgi_server.CPWSGIServer(( '127.0.0.1',8080))already shut down
```

How can I turn it on again ?

Comment: Have you tried any other port than 8080?

Comment: I tried now to kill the processes in the port using sudo fuser -k 8080/tcp and now I don't see that error, But also I found nothing when I open the webpage of the port, I don't know if it is another problem or that command was the wrong one

Comment: Is the server starting correctly `ENGINE Serving on http://127.0.0.1:8080`. Do you try to access your BeagleBone from another computer?

Comment: Yes, I want to access it from another computer in the same network

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tkink the port 8080 is already used. Your command is fine to kill a process running on particular port on Linux.

```
fuser -k 8080/tcp
```

If you try to access your device remotely you have to explicitly configure Cherrypy to bind on all interfaces:

```py
import cherrypy

class HelloWorld(object):
    @cherrypy.expose
    def index(self):
        return "Hello world!"

if __name__ == '__main__':
   cherrypy.config.update({'server.socket_host': '0.0.0.0'} )
   cherrypy.quickstart(HelloWorld())
```

Comment: I added that but still I can't connectTutorial - Hello World

import cherrypy
cherrypy.config.update({'server.socket_host': '0.0.0.0'})
cherrypy.quickstart()
cherrypy.quickstart()

class HelloWorld:
    def index(self):
        return "Hello world!"

Comment: Did you try to curl your page from localhost? Is it working?

Comment: Start your app. ssh your BeagleBone in another shell and `curl -v http://localhost:8080`. You should have `HTTP/1.1 200 OK`.

Comment: I did it exactly like that and run it  , The output of the run is correct as in the tutorial but still in the http://0.0.0.0:8080 not available

Comment: I think the curl works but in 127.0.0.1 here is the output Hello world!* Closing connection #0
root@beaglebone:~# * About to connect() to localhost port 8080 (#0)
-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('
root@beaglebone:~# *   Trying ::1...
-bash: Desktop: command not found
root@beaglebone:~# * Connection refused
-bash: Desktop: command not found
root@beaglebone:~# *   Trying 127.0.0.1...
-bash: Desktop: command not found
root@beaglebone:~# * connected ......................

Comment: at the end it prints hello world, but still I tried both 0.0.0.0:8080 and 127.0.0.1:8080 in my laptop and nothing yet

Comment: Your have to try http://BeagleBoneIP:8080. 0.0.0.0 is just to listen from any ip address.

Comment: Thanks it works now :) I really appreciate your help